Specific postcodes dont work with a Geojson file
I am trying to do a chrolopleth plot, and it works to some extent but not for all postcode, i have listed two sample datasets below. For one set the plot comes out as intended (PIC A) and the other data ends up colouring the whole map . (PIC B). Can someone point me out to what my mistake might be here?
GeoJSON file path : https://github.com/yetzt/postleitzahlen/blob/main/data/postleitzahlen.geojson.br
## IMPORT PACKAGES ##
import json
import plotly.express as px

data_that_works = {'zip_code': ['01623', '01612', '01558'],
        'capacity': [20, 21, 19]}

data_that_doesnt_work = {'zip_code': ['01561', '01619', '01833'],
        'capacity': [20, 21, 19]}

#Read GeoJSON file
with open('postleitzahlen.geojson', 'r') as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)

fig = px.choropleth(data_that_doesnt_work,
                    geojson=geojson,
                    locations='zip_code',
                    color='capacity',
                    featureidkey='properties.postcode',
                    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                    center = {"lat": 51.1657, "lon": 10.4515},
                    )

# Actual plot
fig.show()

PIC A :
supposed map
PIC B :
map with error
I have tried it with another GeoJSON file and that didnt work too. I have a larger data set with hundreds of entries so it is not possible to remove the problematic postcodes.
I have a list of around 15 Postcodes that dont work and cant find a specific pattern in the entries.
